# Ubuntu 15.10 : port 8080 already used

Tags: ubuntu, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have updated my OS from ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.10.
I am developping J2EE webapps. Since I am on 15.10, Eclipse tells me that 8080 port is already used, I need to change it to 8181. It's annoying.
When I do a `netstat -l` , I don't see any 8080 listening port.

Does anyone know why it changed on 15.10?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :8080
```

You would get in the log something like this :

```
tcp        0      0 <IP_ADDR_OF_USED_INTERFACE>:8080             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6947/java
```

So for me, it is the java process that is using this port and his PID is 6947. For my case, it is fine because I am running JBoss and it is using the port 8080 for HTTP protocol.

Let's suppose you have another process (I had a similar problem with an NVidia service using 8080 port but over Windows). You have 2 options :

- Either configure your tomcat server to have an offset (I think this is what you are doing already)
- Either kill that process if it doesn't deserve to stay alive :

  kill -9 6947

Comment: with your command I am getting  this : tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: What about the column of   `<PID>/<ProcessName>`? For my example that was  `6947/java`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the -a switch for all sockets? Once you verify that the port is in fact in use, you just need to find the process using it and kill it.

I believe you can get the process with the -p switch.